# Is there a way to retrieve the count of messages in a PubSub subscription (in realtime)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to achieve batch consuming of a PubSub subscription, retrieving all the messages that were in the subscription at the begining of my process. To do so, I use [PubSub's asynchronous pulling for Java](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull), and the `consumer.ack()` and `consumer.nack()` functions to process exactly the number of messages that I want, and make the subscription redeliver the messages that I have received but not processed yet. My problem being that I did not managed to find a way to retrieve the real time count of messages in my subscription.

I have started to request `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages` metric from Google Cloud Monitoring, but unfortunately the metric has a ~3 minutes latency with the real count of undelivered messages in the subscription.

Is there any way to retrieve this message count on real time ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retrieve the message count in real time, no. Also keep in mind that such a number would not be sufficient to retrieve all of the messages that were in the subscription at the beginning of the process unless you can guarantee that no publishing is happening at the same time.

If there is publishing, then your subscriber could get those messages before messages published earlier, unless you are using [ordered message delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering) and even still, those delivery guarantees are per ordering key, not a total ordering guarantee. If you can guarantee that there are no publishes during this time and/or you are only bringing the subscriber up periodically, then it sounds more like a batch case, which means you may want to consider a database or a GCS file as an alternative place to store the messages for processing.