Read # of items in Firebase PubSub queue
I'm using Firebase PubSub queues quite extensively and I wondered if there is a way to query the current number of items having the queue name at hand.
I'd like to use this so I can monitor how much work is left.
EDIT: I'm using Node, but I suppose the language doesn't matter that much.

PubSub is not a Firebase product, so searching for google cloud pubsub get item count seems the most relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69407408/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-count-of-messages-in-a-pubsub-subscription-in-re and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486087/209103
